# Computing Lie algebra of a subgroup

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, dynamical-systems

I will like to know how does one compute the Lie algebra of an abstractly given subgroup of a Lie group? Specifically, let $G = \mathrm{SO} ( n + 1, 1 )$ and consider the flow
$$
  g_t = \begin{pmatrix}
          \cosh t   &0   &- \sinh t\\
          0         &I_n &0\\
          - \sinh t &0   &\cosh t
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
and the associated *expanding subgroup* $H = \{ h \in G \mid g_{-t} h g_t \to e \textrm{ as } t \to \infty \}$. I want to understand how to get the Lie algebra of $H$ though I do know the final answer.

Comment: Try to derivate your condition, with $h=e^{s\xi}$

Comment: @Léo That did not work out for me. Have you checked if it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathfrak{h}=\lbrace \xi \in \mathfrak{g}, \frac{d}{ds}\vert_{s=0}(g_{-t}e^{s\xi}g_t) \to 0 $ as $t \to \infty \rbrace $

So you make the computation, gives you a condition, and you check who realizes it in $\mathfrak{g}$...

Does it help?

Comment: The above derivative will be $g_{- t} \xi g_t$, right?

Comment: Seems so... What is $\mathfrak{g}$?

Comment: Null trace matrix which anticommute with the n+1,1 "identity matrix"

Comment: So can you conclude?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood $\mathfrak{g}$ to be the Lie algebra of the subgroup $H$ and kept making stupid edits. Yes, the trace should be zero as $\mathrm{SO} ( n + 1, 1 )$ is inside $\mathrm{SL} ( n + 2 )$. In addition, matrices $X \in \mathfrak{g}$ should have $X^T I_{n + 1, 1} + I_{n + 1, 1} X = 0$. Ain't it?

Comment: Thanks @Léo, with your help I have been able to reduce it down to:
$$
  \mathfrak{h} \subset \left \{
  \begin{pmatrix}
    0          &- \mathbf{x}^T &a\\
    \mathbf{x} &0              &\mathbf{y}\\
    a          &\mathbf{y}^T   &0
  \end{pmatrix} \mid \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \in \Bbb{R}^n \right \}
$$
using the injectivity of the exponential map near the origin, in addition :-)